# php: Show X strings after X string in any string?

Tags: php, string, substring, explode

For example, I have 1000 links in this format:

> www.example.com/files/**[project number]**/[something]/[something]

And I want to extract the **project number** from these links:

> www.example.com/files/**4234**/blabla/bla
>
> www.example.com/files/**7653**/blabla/bla
>
> www.example.com/files/**1024**/blabla/bla

I want to say: Print the first 4 characters/digits after the string "**files/**" in the string "the whole URL".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)..

`$linkArray` is an array containing all links as strings.

```
foreach($linkArray as $link){
   $array = explode('/',$link);
   echo $array[2];    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `preg_match()` should do the trick.

```
preg_match("/[0-9]+/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

Store all your links in an array, iterate over the array and use the above to filter the project numbers.

`preg_match()` guarantees that only the first match is returned and will ignore any match following the first 4 digits.

**Tested here:**

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/zj